# Where does this precision loss happen and how to prevent it?

Tags: c++, qt, xml-parsing, precision, gpx

I'm writing a simple tool in Qt which reads data from two GPX (XML) files and combines them in a certain way. I tested my tool with track logs that contain waypoints having 6 decimal digits precision. When I read them from the GPX file, the precision gets reduced to 4 decimal digits (rounded properly). So for example this original tag:

```
<trkpt lat="61.510656" lon="23.777735">
```

turns into this when my tool writes it again:

```
<trkpt lat="61.5107" lon="23.7777">
```

Debug output shows the precision loss happens on this line:

```
double lat = in.attributes().value("", "lat").toString().toDouble();
```

but I can't see why. `in` is a `QXmlStreamReader` reading from a text file handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably when you are *writing* the value back to the XML. Please post that code in your question.

If I had a guess before seeing the code, you are using `QString::number` to convert from the double back to a string. The default precision in the conversion is 6, which corresponds to what you are seeing. You can increase the precision to get all the decimals.

Comment: I put this: qDebug() << "Found wpt" << lat << "," << lon; after the above line and it show lat and lon are already rounded to 4 digits. Unless, of course, qDebug also rounds with the same precision.

Comment: Try: `qDebug() << QString::number(lat, 'f', 10)`

Comment: I'll bet everything eventually uses `QString QString::number(double n, char format = 'g', int precision = 6 )`

Comment: That's the ticket! QString::number was indeed the culprit.